# Getting `eslint' - parsing error, while compiling firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Recently I've started working on a project based on firebase cloud functions and firestore database. I'm writing a cloud function trigger function which will query a "Collection group", on a new document being created.

Below is the cloud function code file:

```
exports.findDealsOnBuy = functions.firestore
    .document('businessmen/{businessmenId}/buy/{buyId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const businessmenId = context.params.businessmenId;
        const buyId = context.params.buyId;
        const buy = snapshot.data();
        functions.logger.info('businessmenId : ', businessmenId, ' buyId : ', buyId, ' buy : ', buy );
        const sellGrpRef = admin.firestore().collectionGroup('sell');
        const querySnapshot = await sellGrpRef.whereEqualTo('goodsName', '==', buy.getGoodsName())
            .whereEqualTo('goodsLocation', '==', buy.getGoodsLocation())
            .whereEqualTo('status', '==', 1)
            .whereEqualTo('status', '==', 5)
            .whereLessThanOrEqualTo('bestPrice', '<=', buy.getBestPrice())
            .orderBy('bestPrice', 'desc')
            .get();
            
            if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                console.log('No matching documents.');
                return;
            } 
            
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
            });
    });
```

But while compiling i am being thrown the below error

```
> C:\Users\Suman\Kamakshi\Ganesh\Burrabazar\Cloudfunctions\functions\index.js
> 31:31  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token sellGrpRef
```

I tried a lot but I am unable to find a clue how to resolve this. Requesting help to resolve.

Comment: You can only use `await` inside `async` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sharing now that I found the await documentation in [MDN Web Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

To wait for a Promise, use the await operator. Within standard JavaScript code, it can only be used inside an async function.

You can use await within a function if you use the async keyword before the function definition. When you wait for a promise to settle, the function is stopped in a non-blocking manner. You get the value back if the promise is kept. The rejected value is thrown if the promise fails.